# MediaRecorder not working

Tags: android

i am using this code to record audio file in android device

```
 private int output_formats[] = {MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4};
private String file_exts[] = {AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP3};



  recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i am using `4.4.2` android device.
now my app is in both android as well as ios device so my recorded audio from `4.4.2` android device not working in ios device 
how can i resolved this?
but this code working properly from other devices i checked using lollipop 5.0 or 6.0 android devices. all recorded audio working properly in ios device.
error in ios:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ca807b0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16170 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16170)}`